# NoSuchProviderException: smtp with log4j SMTP appender

Tags: java, log4j, jms, jakarta-mail, slf4j

I am using log4j to send an email when there is an exception. below is my log4j properties file configuration.

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, R, email
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{1}]: %m%n
log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=10
log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=myhost.com
log4j.appender.email.From=abc@some.com
log4j.appender.email.To=abc@some.com
log4j.appender.email.Subject=Error
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

mine is maven project i have added dependencies for mail.jar, activation.jar and smtp.jar. But on **application server startup** itself i get below error:

```
[ERROR] log4j:ERROR Error occured while sending e-mail notification.
[ERROR] javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp
[ERROR]     at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:782)
[ERROR]     at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:708)
[ERROR]     at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:651)
[ERROR]     at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:631)
[ERROR]     at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:686)
[ERROR]     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:166)
```

Am i missing any thing here? What is the root cause of the error? is it because of **incorrect SMTP host name**? or is it because of any missing/conflicting dependencies?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15637471/772981) about the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need smtp.jar and mail.jar - everything in smtp.jar is also in mail.jar.  Get rid of smtp.jar, although I doubt that will solve your problem.

Also, make sure you don't have any other jar files with JavaMail classes in your classpath, such as javaee.jar or j2ee.jar.

This is most likely a classpath problem of some sort.  JavaMail uses the class loader to find the configuration file that configures the providers such as "smtp".  If the class loader handles resource lookups incorrectly, this problem can occur.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your JavaMail to 1.5.3 which contains the [fix](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/revision/680) for [Bug 6668 -skip unusable Store and Transport classes](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6668).  From the bug report:

> In complex class loading situations, it can be possible for there to be
>   multiple copies of the JavaMail classes.  A Store or Transport defined
>   by one copy may be loaded by another copy, but it won't be usable because
>   they're in different ClassLoaders.  In this case, JavaMail should skip
>   over the unusable class and try to load the class from another ClassLoader.
>
> This can happen, for example, in GlassFish if the application includes the
>   JavaMail classes, the application class loader is configured to prefer
>   application classes over system classes, and the app server itself tries
>   to use JavaMail when running in the context of the application.

You can download the latest snapshot and official releases from the [JavaMail reference implementation](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) home page.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to export smtp.jar to be usable by your webapp.