# Must issue a STARTTLS command first java

Tags: smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail and smtp (gmail), here's my code :

```
import java.util.Properties;    
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Email {    
    Properties emailProperties;
    Session mailSession;
    MimeMessage emailMessage;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException,
            MessagingException {

        Email javaEmail = new Email();

        javaEmail.setMailServerProperties();
        javaEmail.createEmailMessage();
        javaEmail.sendEmail();
    }

    public void setMailServerProperties() {

        String emailPort = "587";//gmail's smtp port

        emailProperties = System.getProperties();
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    }

    public void createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
            MessagingException {
        String[] toEmails = { "to@gmail.com" };
        String emailSubject = "Java Email";
        String emailBody = "This is an email sent by JavaMail api.";

        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
        emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        for (int i = 0; i < toEmails.length; i++) {
            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmails[i]));
        }

        emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
        emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");//for a html email
        //emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email

    }

    public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String fromUser = "yourusername";//just the id alone without @gmail.com
        String fromUserEmailPassword = "your_password";

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");

        transport.connect(emailHost, fromUser, fromUserEmailPassword);
        transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        System.out.println("Email sent successfully.");
    }

}
```

Error Message :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0
Must issue a STARTTLS command first. n80sm23847952pfi.25 - gsmtp
    at
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1020)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:716)
    at
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:388)
    at com.mail.Email.sendEmail(Email.java:68)  at
com.mail.Email.main(Email.java:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing this line:

```
Transport t = session.getTransport("smtps");
```

> You'll have to supply the appropriate username and password needed by
>   your mail server. Note that you can change the protocol to "smtps" to
>   make a secure connection over SSL.

The complete information here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail

Comment: Yes, i am giving a valid username and password. I am getting the following error after changing that line :                                          Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for smtps
 at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:436)
 at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:631)
 at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:612)
 at com.mail.Email.sendEmail(Email.java:65)
 at com.mail.Email.main(Email.java:26)

Comment: It sounds like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980408/java-mail-no-provider-for-smtp

Comment: The supporting jars: mail.jar and activation.jar are present in my classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the above issue occured when I use ibm-was-*.jar. And it got resolve when I switch the jar to Javax.mail-version.jar (version is a number like 1.5.5).